# I need a good plugin for Stereo to 5.1

Tags: mixing, 5.1, dvd, stereo-to-surround, upmixing

its been a while since I have visited the site. Been super busy, I am in need of a plugin to up mix stereo to 5.1. I am using Nuendo 5 and I basically have in the timeline stereo stories with really very little hard SFX's, mainly music and Nats and Dialog. These stories where mixed in Stereo Obviously and I would like a good up mix plugin that works well. Now I know this will not be perfect. But honestly I do not have the time or all the projects to remix these in 5.1 and I also do not really think for TV they are really worth doing this. I just want to spread it out in 5.1 for a little effect. Something I can put on the track and click a button. These are doing to DVD. thanks

yes i can fake this with a bus and reverb or delay to the rears and all, but i want a good plugin. thanks.again.

Answer (score 2):

Soundfield UPM-1. Lower budget solution Waves UM 225 or you could try Iosono Anymix. They all work best with stems though. Try the demos and see what works best for you.  None of these are a "click a button and done product" though, then again, nothing in this field of work is, or rather should be.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the Penteo Surround, and Anymix Pro